# How to guarantee grep returns at least one line

Tags: grep, default

I'd like to run a script that runs a grep command and outputs the result. I expect the grep to return one line, but want to handle the case where there is no matching line (for example if the grepped file does not exist). Is there a way to execute something like

```
line = grep ...
if line is empty
   print "\n"
else
   print line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is examine the return code of grep.

`grep` returns 0 if a line was matched and 1 if no lines were matched.  It returns a value greater than 1 if an error occurred.

```
$ echo "hi" | grep hi
hi
$ echo $?
0
$ echo "hi" | grep hello
$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 2):

In certain circumstances (such as when you have `set -e` in a bash script), you don't want `grep` to exit with status 1, which is the case when the expression provided to `grep` is not matched.

Therefore, **to prevent an exit status of 1** (or higher) being provided back to the terminal or script from which `grep` is being called, use:

```
grep "EXPR" FILE.txt || echo "No match found"
```

Possible outcomes:

1. "EXPR" is matched in FILE.txt -  **Output:** List of matches
2. "EXPR" is not matched in FILE.txt - **Output:** "No match found"
3. Improper arguments to grep or file not found (exit status 2 and higher) - **Output (STDOUT):** "No match found" (along with STDERR message)